# dot in variable name

Tags: php, query-string

I am passing the variable with dot in query string.Php is replacing the dot with under score. So how can i retain the variable name which is having dot in the name

http://localhost/sample.php?one.txt=on&two.txt=on

sample.php

$ret=$_REQUEST['one.txt'];//Not working

Comment: Don't put dots in your variable names.

Comment: What if you're simply trying to integrate with OpenID, which places dots in their query parameters?

Answer (score 27):

The reason PHP is converting your variable name from `one.txt` into `one_txt` is because dots are not valid in variable names.

For more details, look at the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variable names follow the same rules
>   as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or
>   underscore, followed by any number of
>   letters, numbers, or underscores. As a
>   regular expression, it would be
>   expressed thus:
>   '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

You can either account for the change (`.` to `_`) and check for `$_REQUEST['one_txt']` or you can make your HTML form pass a valid variable name instead.

## Edit:

To follow-up on Michael Borgwardt's comment, here's the text from [PHP's documentation about handling variables from external sources](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php):

> Dots in incoming variable names
>
> Typically, PHP does not alter the
>   names of variables when they are
>   passed into a script. However, it
>   should be noted that the dot (period,
>   full stop) is not a valid character in
>   a PHP variable name. For the reason,
>   look at it:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $varname.ext;  /* invalid variable name */
> ?>
> ```
>
> Now, what the parser sees is a
>   variable named $varname, followed by
>   the string concatenation operator,
>   followed by the barestring (i.e.
>   unquoted string which doesn't match
>   any known key or reserved words)
>   'ext'. Obviously, this doesn't have
>   the intended result.
>
> For this reason, it is important to
>   note that PHP will automatically
>   replace any dots in incoming variable
>   names with underscores.

It is indeed a PHP specific thing.

Comment: I don't see how PHP's rules for identifiers are relevant to what query string key names are valid. If anything, this is a PHP-specific convention that exists because of the register_globals feature that nobody should be using anyway because it's horribly insecure.

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt: indeed you make a valid point. It is a PHP specific thing, probably a legacy from the time register_globals was the default. And I hope nobody is using anymore too :)

Answer (score 6):

Use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

```
$get = array();
foreach(explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) as $part)
    {
    $part = explode('=', $part);
    if($key = array_shift($part))
        {
        $get[ $key ] = implode('', $part);
        }
    }
print_r($get);
```

Result for your example
    Array ( [one.txt] => on [two.txt] => on )

Comment: Works. Crazy that PHP doesn't allow for dotted params.

Answer (score 4):

The PHP developers implemented this in order to support register_globals() but if they'd paused for more than one second to consider the consequences then they would have only altered the names imported to the global variable namespace, not in $_POST itself.  There's less than no reason for altering the request variables themselves... well, other than to make PHP incapable of handling standard form submissions.

Here's the solution for POST variables as well, which is probably trickier for more users than the GET solution:

```
function post_data(){    
   $data=explode('&',file_get_contents("php://input"));
   $post=array();
   foreach ($data as $var){
      list($key,$value)=explode('=',$var,2);
      $post[$key]=urldecode($value);
   }
   return $post; 
}
```