# Is it possible to use extract() with an array key name 'some.key'?

Tags: php

If I am going to use the code:

```
extract(
  array(
    'key.name' => 'value',
    'somekey' => 'somevalue'
  )
)
```

Is there some way for me to retrieve the first value? E.g. `${'key.name'}` or similar.

I know I can retrieve the second value with `$somekey` but I am curious if its possible with `.` in the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

> Checks each key to see whether it has a valid variable name.

Nope, it won't extract 'key.name'. You can inspect the $GLOBALS array to see it isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *no*.  Give this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057622/dot-in-variable-name) a read.