# PHP/HTML: Php replaces dot for underline in $_FILES?

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dot in variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057622/dot-in-variable-name)

I have a HTML form with a file input.
This file will be saved as the name given in the name attribute,

ex:

```
<input type='file' name='myfile.jpg'>
```

PHP will then save this file as `myfile.jpg`

The problem is, when the form is submited, the files var replaces the dot "." for underline "_"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

[This is a well documented behavior](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For
>   example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"].